# Java Android: action bar menu items display below the activity instead of top

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I have a simple app with action bar and fragments. After adding the menu, it displays below the activity when in portrait mode.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The menu code also is simple:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/valoda_lv"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/lv"
    android:title="LATVIEŠU"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/valoda_ru"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ru"
    android:title="ПО-РУССКИ"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/valoda_en"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/en"
    android:title="ENGLISH"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in SplitActionBarWhenNarrow option.